# How to insert backdrop between HTML elements using z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

Is it possible to separate child component from parent component using backdrop between them? Backdrop should be outside of parent component.

Because child inherits z-index from parent component, as long as parent will have smaller z-index than backdrop, children will be always behind backdrop.

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-bird-4pde49?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: Please update your question to but the code IN the question as much as possible. The link as react but this seems to be about the rendered HTML and CSS - which might make this easier for someone to answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'm aware that the `z-index` CSSS property makes it possible to stack HTML elements onto one another, however, if elements that overlap do not have this CSS property specified then that element ends up showing (visually) last in Document.

Comment: I know what z-index is used for, but i dont know how to solve this problem